# compare 3 variables in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, boolean-algebra

I am wondering how to compare 3 variables in MATLAB, because MATLAB is comparing first 2 and then result against 3rd. To illustrate with example:

> > > (-1 == -1 == -1)
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 0
> ```
>
> > > (-1 == -1 == 1)
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 1
> ```

My dataset that I am comparing has only -1 and +1 values. Is the only solution is to convert everything to 1's and 0's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
(a == b) && (b == c)
```

Comment: Came here to reply to my own question and found out that it is answered! Thanks!